# Create a track that loops and can end quickly

Tags: composition

For an amateur theatre, we need a track that is played live and loops in the background while all crew are presented. The track should end soon after the presentation, and it is not known how long the presentation takes. How can such a track be created without being too boring.

- A long track may contain more variation, but needs more time if it needs to end at a complete cycle
- A short track can stop anywhere, but may be too repetitive.

Would a short chord progression with changing melodies do the trick?

Edit:

From the comments, I realize that I did not emphased that the music is going to be played live, by living musicians. So there is no stop button.

Comment: Can't you just make the track long enough and then fade it live when the presentation is done?

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername Fade-out does not count. It should work without any sound engineering.

Comment: Sounds tricky. How to ensure that the presentation is always done within the same time span? There's really no one that can turn a knob or change a track at this point in time?

Comment: You can have a short loop or a long loop.  A "short chord progression with changing melodies" still adds up to a long loop.  A system that, when someone presses the button, is clever enough to wait until a cycle ends then stop can surely manage a fade-out of a linear track when the button is pressed?   If the button-presser can also turn a knob, and has ears, he could even arrange a musically logical fade out.  Or a long track could be designed with frequent possible stop points.
Bad question, not thought through sufficiently.

Comment: Old technology, but a 'portable keyboard' playing a music style could do this - you can hit the 'ending' button at any point to generate a true end-point. Would need a player, playing & watching for a cue.

Comment: Any idea what style?

Comment: @Tetsujin: Good one! Love those cheesy drum fills that usually are part of the ending thingies...

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername - I have to admit I used to make those things for a living, back in the 90s ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long loop for variety and a short coda section for ending. When the presentation ends, musicians break into the coda. Done properly must work. Any professional musician can create that (I can)